# What is a good strategy for staying up-to-date with external API's?

Tags: ios, api, youtube, dependencies

My project is reliant on several API's, like Twitter and Youtube for example. Recently, Youtube deprecated their old API, and it caused issues with my team's iPad app.

We could have stayed ahead of the change if we were paying attention to Youtube's announcements of the upcoming deprecation. But alas, we were not and the idea of staying up to date with all of our dependencies manually(browsing the web) seems exhausting and inefficient.

I have found the following tool to help notify when changes occur with external library dependencies, https://libraries.io. However, this does not help with API dependencies.

Besides checking the API source webpages every so often, I was wondering if anyone had suggestions on how to stay notified and up-to-date with news regarding updates to a specified list of external API's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time looking at different options, I have found a solution that is not perfect, but seems to work best at fitting this need.

**Solution Description**

This solution uses a combination of Twitter, Google Scripts, and website [blogtrottr.com](http://www.blogtrottr.com). I am creating a twitter list of reliable dev handles that often post updates on new API. For example I made a list that contained @twitterapi and @YouTubeDev. Used Google Scripts to create an online feed out of the twitter list. Then used blogtrottr to email me every time that feed gets a new posting.

**Steps to Implement**

1. Create a twitter list of reliable handles that often post about updates to their API
2. Create an RSS Feed from that Twitter list. The details for how to do this can be found [here](http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-rss-feed/28149/).
3. Plug that url that you get from Google Script into blogtrotter.

I did find some other ways to do this, but so far this is the only solution that was 100% free!